# Is my water heater tank system normal?

Tags: water-heater, boiler, central-heating

I bought a heating system a year ago for my house.
It is a water heater tank. The hot water inside is heated
when the price of electricity is cheaper during the night and
two hours in the middle of the day. (10pm - 6am and 1pm - 3pm)

The buffer has a capacity of 800 liters. I draw a block
diagram of it (done with paint, my apologies for cosmetic)
The heating elements include a thermostat inside. According to their
specification they are able to heat until 85 degres. The thermometer 1 shows 60 degres C when heaters switch off automaticaly. The thermometer 2 on the top shows 80 degres. The power of two heating elements is 9 kw each.

[image]

My house is 150m2, built in the 1990's, only roof has isolation, and windows are triple gazing.
The average temperature outside is zero in winter and I am in mountains.

My main problem is that when it is less than 0 outside in the average, the tank is hot water empty at 10 am, three hours before the next cheap electricity time slot.

I was wondering if the architecture of my system is correct? Is it normal that the temperature is 80 on the top and 60 in the middle after a heating session?
When the tank delivers water to radiators, the temperature is also 60 degres on that pipe.

Edit: There is a temperature sensor in the first floor of the house. It launches the pump and delivers hot water to radiators with the following hysterisis rule: When temperature is half a degree above the command it starts the pump, when half a degree below stops it. My command is 20°, so 19.5 and 20.5 are lower and upper thresholds

Comment: can you adjust the mixing valve

Comment: yes it is possible. I guess the range is from 40 to 60, now it is set at 50. I can also configure the speed of the pump

Comment: Options: 1 Increase the temp inside the boiler, 2 slow down the heating consumption

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more the option 2? My pump is controled by a temperature hysteresis sensor

Comment: if you must wait for cheaper electricity but can tolerate slower warming up, then set the mixing valve to 30/70 so it will slower consumption of the hot water, but it will also slower heat up the rooms

Comment: I am afraid that slowering the heat up won't be enough to compensate the decrease of temperature

Comment: I think it will, since you are not consuming so much of hot water

Comment: Thanks trying to help, but I am lost, with the 30/70 and why slower would help. Finally slow or fast the heat is transferred to the rooms and the boiler is going to be empty slower but not compensating the decrease of temperature of the room? It is able to decrease from 20.5 to 19.5 in an hour when less than zero outside

Comment: I'm surprised that the temperature difference in the buffer tank is so large (80°C vs. 60°C) at the time that the heating elements turn off. If the sketch is even vaguely accurate then the bottom of the tank is likely considerably cooler. Are you sure that the pump on the tank is working properly to reduce the temperature stratification?

Comment: @HABO the pump is ON when heating and looks to work